# Get values on specific key on multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
Array([130] => Array
       (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [first_name] => John
                [last_name] => Smith
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [first_name] => Jane
                [last_name] => Doe
            )
    [123] => Array
      (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [first_name] => Ann
                [last_name] => Green
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [first_name] => Thor
                [last_name] => Grey
            )
        )
```

How to make array like this

```
   Array(
         [130] => Array
          (
            [first_name] => "John, Jane"
         [123] => Array
         (
           [first_name] => "Ann, Thor"
         )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick and simple solution using a [`foreach()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and a [variable by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php):

```
foreach($your_array as &$current) {
    $current = array(
        'first_name' => $current[0]['first_name'] . ', ' . $current[1]['first_name']
    );
}
```

But assuming that you might have multiple people in your sub-arrays rather than just two, here's a better solution:

```
foreach($your_array as &$current) {
    $to_append = array(); // use a temporary array
    foreach($current as $sub_array) {
        $to_append[] = $sub_array['first_name']; // add each first name to temp
    }
    // overwrite current main array iteration with imploded temporary array
    $current = array('first_name' => implode(', ', $to_append));
}
```

--

## Update

Here's another solution that doesn't use a `foreach()`, instead using a combination of [`array_walk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) and [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) with variables by reference:

```
array_walk($your_array, function(&$array_branch) {
    $names = array_map(function($a){
        return $a['first_name']; // return all the first names
    }, $array_branch);

    // combine the first names together
    $array_branch = array('first_name' => implode(', ', $names)); 
});
```

`$array_branch` represents each array inside your main array (keys 130 and 123) and is passed by reference so its value is overwritten each time